# SQL query with w3schools db

Tags: sql

I should have asked multiple questions in my other post. Thanks to all who have helped, I am now stuck on another one..

Using the [w3schools db](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all), List SupplierID, SupplierName and ItemSupplied (count of number of items supplied by a supplier), sort the list first by number of items supplied (descending) and then by supplier name (ascending)

```
SELECT     supplierid, 
           suppliername, 
           p.productname, 
           Count(s.supplierid) AS itemssupplied 
FROM       [Suppliers]         AS s 
INNER JOIN [Products]          AS p 
ON         p.supplierid = s.supplierid 
GROUP BY   p.productid, 
           p.productname 
ORDER BY   Count (p.productid, p.productname) DESC 
order BY   s.suppliername
```

It's giving me an error, then again I am ordering by multiple ones. I think there's something I am not quite understanding here.

**My other question is**

List customers for each category and the total of order placed by that customer in a given category. In the query show three columnm: CategoryName, CustomerName, and TotalOrders (which is price * quantity for orders for a given customer in a given category). Sort this data in descending order by TotalOrders.

```
SELECT cg.CategoryName, 
       c.CustomerName, 
       Sum(p.Price * od.Quantity) AS TotalOrders 
FROM   [products] AS p 
       INNER JOIN [orderdetails] AS od 
               ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID 
       INNER JOIN [orders] AS o 
               ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID 
       INNER JOIN [customers] AS c 
               ON c.customerID = o.CustomerID 
       INNER JOIN [categories] AS cg 
               ON cg.CategoryID = p.CategoryID 
GROUP  BY c.CustomerName 
ORDER  BY TotalOrders DESC
```

Can someone please check if my query is correct? Thank you once again!

Comment: If you want to know what is “giving me an error” you have to **tell us the error**.

Comment: Check if your query is correct? Would you also like a grade like "A" or "F minus"?

Comment: @DourHighArch the error was 
Error1: could not prepare statement (1 near "ORDER":syntax error). I tried to follow the error and change it, but it gave me a similar one so I wasn't sure where I am off by

Comment: `[OrderDetails]` it not a valid SQL identifier. Standard SQL uses `"` to quote identifiers. Are you sure w3cschools (which is usually a site full of errors) supports this non-standard syntax?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am only on my first class for queries.. and the instructor pointed us to w3schools db. I am not sure what kind of db this is.. so I am confused as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems with the first query:

1. You're grouping by `ProductID` and `ProductName` even though you want the *number of items supplied by a supplier*, which means that you want to group by `SupplierID` and `SupplierName`.
2. You're supplying too many arguments to the `COUNT` function, which takes a single column name or `*`.
3. You've included a `ProductName` column in your results, which is not called for.
4. You need to `ORDER BY` both the number of products supplied and the `SupplierName`.

With those points in mind:

```
SELECT 
    s.SupplierID, 
    s.SupplierName, 
    COUNT(p.ProductID) AS ItemsSupplied
FROM 
    [Suppliers] AS s
    INNER JOIN [Products] AS p ON p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
GROUP BY 
    s.SupplierID, s.SupplierName
ORDER BY 
    ItemsSupplied DESC,
    s.SupplierName ASC
```

Your second query is quite close, you're just missing one point, which is that you're looking for *total of order placed by that customer in a **given category***. This means that in addition to grouping by `c.CustomerName`, you need to group by `cg.CategoryID`:

```
SELECT 
    cg.CategoryName, 
    c.CustomerName, 
    SUM(p.Price*od.Quantity) AS TotalOrders
FROM 
    [Products] AS p
    INNER JOIN [OrderDetails] AS od ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
    INNER JOIN [Orders] AS o ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    INNER JOIN [Customers] AS c ON c.customerID = o.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN [Categories] AS cg ON cg.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
GROUP BY 
    c.CustomerName, cg.CategoryID
ORDER BY 
    TotalOrders DESC
```

Comment: thank you very much Andrew, that was a really good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

You are really close but you only need to state `ORDER BY` once (also make sure to include all shown fields in your `GROUP BY` unless you are aggregating them):

```
SELECT SupplierID, SupplierName, p.ProductName, count(s.SupplierID) AS ItemsSupplied
FROM [Suppliers] AS s
INNER JOIN [Products] AS p ON p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.ProductName, SupplierID, SupplierName -- Added SupplierID, SupplierName
ORDER BY COUNT (p.productID, p.ProductName) DESC, s.SupplierName
```

Notice that you just place multiple sorts on the same line with a comma separating them.

**Question 2**

You're almost there but you need to group by any field that is not being aggregated. So in order not to get a parsing error, I added the `cg.CategoryName` to the `GROUP BY` line.

```
SELECT cg.CategoryName, c.CustomerName, Sum(p.Price*od.Quantity) AS TotalOrders
FROM [Products] AS p
INNER JOIN [OrderDetails] AS od ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN [Orders] AS o ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN [Customers] AS c ON c.customerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Categories] AS cg ON cg.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
GROUP BY c.CustomerName, cg.CategoryName     --Added CategoryName
ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC
```

Comment: The first one gave me "Error1: could not prepare statement (1 wrong number of arguments to function COUNT())" can I only use Count once? 

Thank you for the second question advice!

Comment: Ah... it looks like you forgot to Group By SupplierID and SupplierName. I missed that but have now edited my answer.

Comment: thank you @DanK, I am still having a little bit of trouble understanding group so many columns together. Does it just make it into one row each?

Answer (score 0):

The first one has two order by clauses

```
ORDER BY COUNT (p.productID, p.ProductName) DESC
```

and

```
ORDER BY s.SupplierName
```

also some databases will complain when order by columns for queries using group by are not included in the selected columns